# buck converter doesn't work

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-charge-controller, buck-boost

I am doing my project. and it's about a DC-DC converter.
I am using HCPL 3021 as a driver for the MOSFET IPPR045C7.
in open loop cicuit, I am using Vin=60V, with duty cycly = 60% of PWM signal (F=20KHz).
The output voltage should be Vout=36V. But it's not. I got Vout=16V.
even with a load connected the voltage remains wrong.[image]
the circuit is shown in the joined picture.
Can you please help me and tell me what's wrong with circuit?
Is the ground connection wrong?

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you please help me and tell me what's wrong with circuit?

Your MOSFET is an N channel type and you have put it in the circuit as a source follower. Your gate driver can produce no more than 15 volts to drive the gate hence, the output from the source will be several volts below this figure and fairly load dependent.

To properly turn on that MOSFET you need your gate voltage to rise above the positive rail of your main power supply of 60 volts. You are nowhere near this happening with your circuit.

You should connect Vee of the HCPL3120 to the incoming positive rail and use a 15 volt supply that is floating and can be connected to the positive rail of 60 volts thus making a driver rail of 75 volts - that will then allow the gate to be properly driven.

Comment: the Vout is not exactly correspond to the Vin x Duty Cycle

Comment: @RAMZI why did you make that comment. I did read your question before answering.

Comment: the Max of  Vcc-Vee = 30 V. Can you please send how I should connect the HCPL3120. Because I didn't really get what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: You need to power rail that is about 10 to 15 volts above your current 30 volt rail. Make this using an isolating dc/dc converter. Then connect the power rails of the opto (pin 8 and pin 5) between 40 volts and 30 volts. Now it will drive the NMOS.